Do I need to turn off the main power switch on a digital board when plugged into a Furman power sequencer
I have used power sequencers for years and recently someone told me I still need to turn off the main power switch on the board even though it has powered off with the sequencer. The sequencer is a Furman PS-8R and the mixer is an Allen & Heath GLD112. I have a librarian at a school telling me so. I know I don't but she is insisting and I want something to show her. She won't read a manual
